# How to populate a dropdown from another dropdown's selected value in Django

Tags: python, html, django

I have 2 models, one model is of the `users` and another of `videos`. `user_id` is acting as a foreign key for the `videos` model.
I have created 2 dropdowns using the select/option tags.

models.py

```
class Users(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Videos(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Users,on_delete=CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.name
```

I have populated the first dropdown by retrieving all the users from the DB and sending them to the template in views.py. What I want is, as soon as I select one of the users in the first dropdown all the videos corresponding to that particular user should appear as options in the second dropdown.

```
<div class="mb-3">
   <label class="py-1" for="Select_participant">Select Participant:</label>
   <select name = "selected_user" class="form-select" required aria-label="select example">
   {% for user in users %}
       <option value="{{user.id}}">{{user.name}}</option>
   {% endfor %}
   </select>
</div>

<div class="mb-3">
    <label class="py-1" for="URL">Select Video:</label>
    <select class="form-select" required aria-label="select example">
        <option value="/path">video1</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I am not able to figure out to achieve this. I was thinking like first sending the value of the selected user to the backend, and then filtering the videos w.r.t that particular user and then again rendering the template, but it will become much complex. Are there any easy ways to achieve this? Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: There are packages like https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/

Comment: normally it would need JavaScript to get new data without reloading all HTML.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html

Comment: @Razenstein 's suggestion is what you need to help you do what you want. On the PARTICIPANT's dropdown-change run an ajax request to return the list of videos related to that participant and on success have it populate the dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

You could use htmx. On selection of the first dropdown, you swap the the html of the second dropdown by calling a view with the selected user. This view just gets the relevant videos and returns them as a small piece of html inside your form. You could write it directly in JavaScript, jQuery, etc but htmx makes it a lot easier. https://htmx.org/

Here's an article that explains more on how to use it in Django.

https://www.mattlayman.com/blog/2021/how-to-htmx-django/

There are others. Just Google htmx and django